# Trouble with links to symbol pages generated by Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench, documentation

I am having some troubles with documentation generated by wolfram workbench. When i try to open symbol page created with workbench by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> I get a search page instead of my symbol page. When I try to open page with make template (<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) I get the message that the page does not exist, even though I can find it through search.

My guess is that page is not linked with symbol, but I don't know why it happens. Is there any way to fix it ?

UPD:
My Mathematica version is 9;
By using <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> i mean this:

[image]

The message with will show up only if notebook was launched with workbench, in other cases Mathematica will just ignore this attempt.

If I set PackletInfo.m like this:

```
    Paclet[
      Name -> "TheoryOfComputation",
      Version -> "1.0.0",
      MathematicaVersion -> "9+",
      Description -> "Theory of Computation package",
      Creator -> "Me",
      Extensions -> {
      {
        "Kernel", 
        Context -> {"TheoryOfComputation`"}
      },
      { "Documentation", 
        Resources-> {"Guides/TheoryOfComputation"},
        Language -> "English",
        MainPage->"Guides/TheoryOfComputation",
        LinkBase->"TheoryOfComputation"
      }
   }]
```

I can type something like MyPackage`MySymbol, press F1 and this works fine. But with this i can't use function templates. Also, typing MySymbol and pressing F1 leads to search page again, even thought result of ?MySymbol have link to documentation page

Comment: Let me try to recap: `F1` takes you directly to the function help page for built-in functions, but for your own functions to a search page, right? I can confirm this happens, but can't reproduce the `Ctr+Shift+K` behaviour. What Mathematica version are you on? And can you post the contents of your `PacletInfo.m` file? 
Have you tried reaching out to WRI on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `PacletInfo.m` file in

AddOns/Applications/YourPackage/PacketInfo.m

The file should be something like:

```
Paclet[
    Name -> "YourPackageName",
    Version -> "9.0.0",
    MathematicaVersion -> "9+",
    Extensions ->  
        {   
            {"Documentation", Language -> All, MainPage -> "Guides/YourGudePage"}
        }   
]
```

Then run (not sure if this is really needed)

```
PacletManager`RebuildPacletData[]
```

Then the links should work. If you create your package with Workbench you can double click the file and a PacletInfo editor will open.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you missed an extension that makes it work on 9; see my answer for the details.

Comment: @TeakeNutma, that depends on the purpose functionality of the package.

Comment: No, you need that extra line in order for the Mathematica 9 paclet manager to resolve links to symbols. And what do you mean with "purpose functionality of the package"?

Comment: @TeakeNutma, what I posted works fine for me for a documentation package.

Comment: We both may have misunderstood the question ... I have withdrawn my answer.